# Custom tablayout indicator

Tags: android-viewpager, android-tablayout, indicator

Anybody knows how to custom tablayout to use for viewpager like this [Tablayout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/09bXM.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use some library for the indicator, please checkout the links for libraries mentioned below

**Github Links:**

1. [viewpagerindicator](https://github.com/zhpanvip/viewpagerindicator)
2. [dotsindicator](https://github.com/tommybuonomo/dotsindicator)

Comment: Thanks for your assistance but honestly ,I want custom it by myseft.

Comment: @ThànhTâmCao take reference from that library. Just go through the code how they did it and you can customize it on the basis of your own requirement.

Comment: Its a good practice when using dots indicator with some customize